# Как chrome решает подставлять ли пароль в форму?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

Есть одно и тоже приложение на `React`, развернутое на разных поддоменах. Если открыть форму редактирования юзера, то на одном домене в форму вставлен пароль, а на другом - нет. Хотя сохраненные в хроме пароли есть и для одного и для другого поддомена. Как этим управлять и от чего это зависит? Чтобы отладить это, мне нужно воспроизвести автоподстановку и на втором домене тоже, но я не могу это сделать никаким способом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По type password, и, возможно, по name password (но это только предположения)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar да, но приложения полностью одинаковые, т.е. name и type в этих полях тоже одинаковые. И если на каждом поддомене кликнуть в поле, то вываливается список сохраненных паролей для этого поддомена. Но в одном случае он вставлен сразу, а в другом - нет.

Comment: https? Наличие заранее запомненного пароля?

Comment: @andreymal да, действительно, разница в https. Спасибо